# how to avoid 403 status code while scraping using Beautiful soup- python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, http-status-code-403

````
```
import urllib.request 
import urllib.parse
import urllib.error
#from selenium import webdriver
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
   'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
   'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
   'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
   'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
   'Connection': 'keep-alive'}    
my_session = requests.session()
for_cookies = my_session.get("https://www.movoto.com")
my_url = 'https://www.movoto.com/san-francisco-ca/'
response = my_session.get(my_url, timeout=5,headers=hdr, cookies=cookies)
print(response.status_code)  

```
````

'I am trying to scrape real estate data for learning purpose and Expecting status code 200 but I am getting 403. how to avoid this error

Comment: If you are in Europe, it seems to fail due to GDPR. Launching the url in browser, I get "403 - Permission Denied.

European users are prohibited from visiting Movoto’s website due to GDPR compliance requirements, please see Movoto’s Terms of Use and Privacy Policy for further details."

Answer (score 1):

I think your headers are incorrect. Try the code below. Also, would be easier to access the listing through the api, so I adjusted for that.

It also restricts you if you make too many request sin a certain time frame, so I added a random sleep if that pops up.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import math
import time
import random

hdr = {
'sec-ch-ua': '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="90", "Google Chrome";v="90"',
'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36'}    

url = 'https://www.movoto.com/api/v/search/'

page = 1
payload= {
'path': '/san-francisco-ca/p-%s/' %page,
'fullUrlPath': '/san-francisco-ca/p-%s/' %page}


def get_data(url,payload,hdr):
    try:
        jsonData = requests.get(url, params=payload, headers=hdr).json()
        return jsonData, True
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        randSleep = random.randint(500, 1500)/100
        print('Will rerty in %s seconds.' %(int(randSleep)))
        time.sleep(randSleep)
        return None, False
    

success = False
while success == False:
    jsonData, success = get_data(url, payload, hdr)

total_pages = math.ceil(jsonData['data']['totalCount'] / 50)

df = pd.DataFrame()
for page in range(1, total_pages+1):
    if page==1:
        pass
    else:
        success = False
        payload= {
            'path': '/san-francisco-ca/p-%s/' %page,
            'fullUrlPath': '/san-francisco-ca/p-%s/' %page}
        while success == False:
            jsonData, success = get_data(url, payload, hdr)
        
    data = jsonData['data']['listings']
    data = pd.json_normalize(data)    
    df = df.append(data, sort=False)
    print('%s of %s' %(page, total_pages))
    
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

*Output:** Just showing first 5 rows

[2041 rows x 61 columns]

```
print(df.head(5).to_string())
  closePrice  daysOnMovoto                                    id                                                         tnImgPath             listDate         listingAgent  listPrice  lotSize  sqftTotal  mlsDbNumber  mlsNumber  bath  bed openHouses                 officeListName  photoCount         propertyType      propertyTypeDisplayName  yearBuilt zipCode                                                                                     path  status houseRealStatus priceChange                            propertyId      visibility soldDate            createdAt  imageDownloaderStatus     onMarketDateTime                           virtualTourLink nhsDetails  isNHS  isSold listingByMovoto  priceRaw  isVideoTour  is3DTour videoTourLink                               virtualLink mls.dateHidden  mls.id geo.state       geo.city    geo.lat     geo.lng geo.zipcode geo.subPremise              geo.address address  longitude  latitude nhsBuilderName  nhsBuilderId nhsListingType  nhsMarketName  nhsMarketId nhsPlanName nhsCommunityName  nhsCommunityId activeUnderContract
0       None             0  87272168-8401-4981-9f57-88da8f6935fb             https://pi.movoto.com/p/110/421541970_0_QYM3JF_p.jpeg  2021-04-22 00:00:00         Michael Shaw    1575000  39396.0        0.0          110  421541970   3.0  2.0         []            Vanguard Properties          46                CONDO                  Condominium     2008.0   94110          san-francisco-ca/3620-19th-st-5-san-francisco-ca-94110/pid_0pqyoad48g/for-sale/  Active          ACTIVE        None  3e4a38b3-9877-4bbe-9bcf-f91b7ca84965  NO_RESTRICTION     None  2021-04-27 07:36:13                      7  2021-04-22 00:00:00  https://www.youtube.com/embed/CrUZ2VTlLm       None  False   False           False   1575000        False      True                https://www.youtube.com/embed/CrUZ2VTlLm           None     110        CA  San Francisco  37.760155 -122.424316       94110          APT 5          3620 19th St #5     NaN        NaN       NaN            NaN           NaN            NaN            NaN          NaN         NaN              NaN             NaN                 NaN
1       None             0  76315f62-f779-422a-aa61-28ed652a6c9d             https://pi.movoto.com/p/110/421542506_0_f2ffUN_p.jpeg  2020-09-20 00:00:00    Karen Wong-Dunlap     949000  43147.0     1160.0          110  421542506   2.0  2.0         []           KW Peninsula Estates          46                CONDO                  Condominium     2002.0   94103  san-francisco-ca/140-s-van-ness-ave-apt-529-san-francisco-ca-94103-110_506649/for-sale/  Active          ACTIVE        None  69609912-16a2-41b4-988d-c1fef16ea86e  NO_RESTRICTION     None  2021-04-27 07:21:11                      7  2020-09-20 00:00:00               Https://vimeo.com/535642471       None  False   False           False    949000        False      True                             Https://vimeo.com/535642471           None     110        CA  San Francisco  37.771689 -122.418676       94103        APT 529  140 S Van Ness Ave #529     NaN        NaN       NaN            NaN           NaN            NaN            NaN          NaN         NaN              NaN             NaN                 NaN
2       None             0  7c820dad-3bfa-40d8-9491-20234839c1d7             https://pi.movoto.com/p/110/421542207_0_Fj2jqN_p.jpeg  2021-03-15 00:00:00  Jennifer Holderness    1695000   3088.0     1848.0          110  421542207   2.0  3.0         []                        Compass          20  SINGLE_FAMILY_HOUSE  Residential - Single Family     1939.0   94127             san-francisco-ca/71-ulloa-st-san-francisco-ca-94127/pid_jadyoad48g/for-sale/  Active          ACTIVE        None  717a7eae-cd86-4786-ae36-1de0be63c5af  NO_RESTRICTION     None  2021-04-27 07:21:10                      7  2021-03-15 00:00:00               Https://vimeo.com/541837642       None  False   False           False   1695000        False      True                             Https://vimeo.com/541837642           None     110        CA  San Francisco  37.744516 -122.454475       94127                             71 Ulloa St     NaN        NaN       NaN            NaN           NaN            NaN            NaN          NaN         NaN              NaN             NaN                 NaN
3       None             0  2259c10e-bbdc-412f-a25e-a38009253ffc  https://pi2.movoto.com/1.8.235/novaimgs/images/nophoto_small.svg  2021-04-01 00:00:00       Patrick Lowell    1095000   2805.0     1212.0          110  421542414   2.0  2.0         []                        Compass           0  SINGLE_FAMILY_HOUSE  Residential - Single Family     1928.0   94127            san-francisco-ca/135-manor-dr-san-francisco-ca-94127/pid_nckyoad48g/for-sale/  Active          ACTIVE        None  9fc91890-2374-4043-98de-37bc1bde1341  NO_RESTRICTION     None  2021-04-27 07:21:10                      0  2021-04-01 00:00:00                       Http://135Manor.com       None  False   False           False   1095000        False      True                                     Http://135Manor.com           None     110        CA  San Francisco  37.728693 -122.463995       94127                            135 Manor Dr     NaN        NaN       NaN            NaN           NaN            NaN            NaN          NaN         NaN              NaN             NaN                 NaN
4       None             0  2ba786b5-61af-481b-b97c-502fb6a6651a             https://pi.movoto.com/p/110/421542298_0_QmmrnY_p.jpeg  2021-04-25 00:00:00          Jack Murray    1295000   1084.0     1496.0          110  421542298   2.0  3.0         []  Berkshire Hathaway-Franciscan          48  SINGLE_FAMILY_HOUSE  Residential - Single Family     1900.0   94110             san-francisco-ca/685-capp-st-san-francisco-ca-94110/pid_81pyoad48g/for-sale/  Active          ACTIVE        None  47ab39ad-afa9-4a7e-b533-55ce177fc453  NO_RESTRICTION     None  2021-04-27 07:21:09                      7  2021-04-25 00:00:00               Https://www.685Capp.com/mls       None  False   False           False   1295000        False      True                             Https://www.685Capp.com/mls           None     110        CA  San Francisco  37.755889 -122.417596       94110                             685 Capp St     NaN        NaN       NaN            NaN           NaN            NaN            NaN          NaN         NaN              NaN             NaN                 NaN
```